# XSL Find Last Node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

> My XMl is Like This.. How can i find the last Node for the current
>   Parent ID..

```
<I ID="958" ParentID="1" TOTAL="12"/>
<I ID="959"  ParentID="958"     TOTAL="0"/>
<I ID="960" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0"/>
<I ID="961" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0"/>
<I ID="962" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0"/>
<I ID="963" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0" />
<I ID="964" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0"/>
<I ID="965"  ParentID="958" TOTAL="0"/>
<I ID="964" ParentID="958"  TOTAL="0"/>
<I ID="967" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0"/>
<I ID="968" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0"/>
<I ID="969" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0" />
<I ID="970" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0" />
<I ID="971" ParentID="2" TOTAL="12"/>
<I ID="972" ParentID="971"  TOTAL="0"/>
<I ID="973" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0"/>
<I ID="974" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0"/>
<I ID="975" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0"/>
<I ID="976" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0" />
<I ID="977" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0"/>
<I ID="978"  ParentID="971" TOTAL="0"/>
<I ID="979" ParentID="971"  TOTAL="0"/>
<I ID="980" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0"/>
<I ID="981" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0"/>
<I ID="982" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0" />
<I ID="983" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0" />
```

> I want to find the

```
 <I ID="970" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0" />
 <I ID="983" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0" />
```

> and Want to change the design for this...
>   XSLT 1.0

Comment: Good question, +1. The wanted nodes can be selected with a single, simple and short XPath expression.

Comment: @_Rocky111: Was my answer useful to you?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just after the last `I` element for a given `ParentID`, then the following will do the trick

```
<xsl:copy-of select="I[@ParentID=$currentParentID][last()]"/>
```

If you are after the last `I` element for each `ParentID`, then this should do it

```
<xsl:for-each select="I">
    <xsl:if test="empty(following-sibling::I[@ParentID=current()/@ParentID])">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

There is a good XLST quick reference at http://www.mulberrytech.com/quickref/XSLT_1quickref-v2.pdf

Comment: i did't get how to use this.....
<xsl:copy-of select="I[@ParentID=$currentParentID][last()]"/>

Comment: $currentParentId is supposed to be set to some specific ParentID. e.g., `<xsl:variable name="currentParentID" select="958"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

- Get the node-set of all the items with the parent ID of the first parent.
- Get a count of all items in that node-set.
- Run an if-then on that node-set, returning the subject node if position() equals the count minus 1.

Be careful here. XML is unordered by nature. Without keys, there is no difference between the second and the 13th elements other than the fact that they happened to occur in that order this time. "Happened to," isn't guaranteed to happen another time. Your source should be providing either an ordering key or some other reason why that 13th line is different from the 11 before it.

If you provide your existing XSLT, I can give you some pointers on modifying it to include this.

Answer (score 0):

**This simple transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pId" select="958"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="/*/I[@ParentID= $pId][last()]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<t>
    <I ID="958" ParentID="1" TOTAL="12"/>
    <I ID="959"  ParentID="958"     TOTAL="0"/>
    <I ID="960" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0"/>
    <I ID="961" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0"/>
    <I ID="962" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0"/>
    <I ID="963" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0" />
    <I ID="964" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0"/>
    <I ID="965"  ParentID="958" TOTAL="0"/>
    <I ID="964" ParentID="958"  TOTAL="0"/>
    <I ID="967" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0"/>
    <I ID="968" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0"/>
    <I ID="969" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0" />
    <I ID="970" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0" />
    <I ID="971" ParentID="2" TOTAL="12"/>
    <I ID="972" ParentID="971"  TOTAL="0"/>
    <I ID="973" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0"/>
    <I ID="974" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0"/>
    <I ID="975" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0"/>
    <I ID="976" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0" />
    <I ID="977" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0"/>
    <I ID="978"  ParentID="971" TOTAL="0"/>
    <I ID="979" ParentID="971"  TOTAL="0"/>
    <I ID="980" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0"/>
    <I ID="981" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0"/>
    <I ID="982" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0" />
    <I ID="983" ParentID="971" TOTAL="0" />
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<I ID="970" ParentID="958" TOTAL="0"/>
```

**Do Note**: The appropriate parentId is passed as a global, external parameter to the transformation, which makes it highly re-usable.